# Remove the Extra Space between Labels

Tags: apex, visualforce, html, css

Here is my VF Code:

```
    <span style="padding:10px;">
        <label>{!wrapper.used}</label>
        /
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!wrapper.total}"/>
        USED IN&nbsp;
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!wrapper.period}"/>
        DAYS
    </span>
```

The output on the Page is:

```
0 /3 USED IN 90 DAYS
```

The space after '0' is irritating and I am not able to remove it.
The expected output is:

```
0/3 USED IN 90 DAYS
```

Please let me know what can be done. I am sure I am missing something very basic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a single label :

```
<Apex:outputLabel value="{!wrapper.used}/{!wrapper.total} USED IN {!wrapper.period} DAYS"/>
```